# AWS ECR Lifecycle rule for multi tag image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

I have tagged same image with `my-app-beta-0.5` and `my-app-latest`, if my AWS ECR lifecycle policy decides to delete `my-app-beta-0.5`, will it also delete `my-app-latest` tag ?

I think yes, in dry run it shows both will be deleted given its a same image with same sha.

How can I add a rule to skip expire for images tagged like `my-app-latest` ?

One approach I can think of adding high priority policy for `my-app-latest` and expire after very long time like 5 or 10 year. But can I do anything better here ?